# UITextView doesn't display in multiple lines

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, mobile, uitextview

I have a `UITableViewCell` that has a `UITextView`. When the table loads all of the text in each `UITextView` appears in a single line. I created the `UITextView` in `IB` with a white text color. How do I get it to display in multiple lines, and why did the text color switch to black?

The height of each `UITableViewCell` is correct. It used to display the text in multiple lines after I refreshed the table by pulling down, but for some reason that stopped working too.

If there's any other information you require, please let me know.

Here's the relevant code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object {

BIDChatCell *cell = (BIDChatCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[BIDChatCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

// Configure the cell

cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

cell.userLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"username"];
NSString *time = [object objectForKey:@"time"];
NSString *date = [time substringToIndex:10];
cell.timeLabel.text = date;

NSString *chatText = [object objectForKey:@"text"];
UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
CGSize size = [chatText sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(200.0f, 1000.0f) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeCharacterWrap];
cell.textStringView.frame = CGRectMake(75, 15, size.width +20, size.height + 20);
cell.textStringView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14.0];
cell.textStringView.text = chatText;
[cell.textStringView sizeToFit];
[cell.textStringView.textContainer setSize:cell.textStringView.frame.size];

CGRect frame = cell.textStringView.frame;
frame.size.height = cell.textStringView.contentSize.height;
cell.textStringView.frame = frame;

[cell layoutSubviews];
return cell;
```

}

Here's an image: [image: Screenshot]

Comment: Please try to add: [cell layoutSubviews] before return cell

Comment: Have you implemented the `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` method?

Comment: Could you provide screen shot of your table containing textview ,i.e., in-correct and correct way. So that would make your question clear and  would provide answer according. Else u should try for heightforrow.

Comment: @SebastianBorggrewe I tried your suggestion of [cell layoutSubviews] but it didn't change anything

Comment: @user2492566 have you found the solution? I am facing the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the height of the textView like so:

```
CGRect frame = cell.textStringView.frame;
frame.size.height = cell.textStringView.contentSize.height;
cell.textStringView.frame = frame;
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested, but it didn't change anything

Answer (score 0):

Does the UITextView have the proper `autoresizingMask`?

It likely needs it set to `(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight)` to allow the textview to grow (as it normally uses a UIScrollView instead)